# Jenkins BlueOcean is not able to interprete URL properly

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-blueocean

I've an issue: When I've a jenkins blue ocean window, it works fine, but if I go away and come back like 10 minutes afters, it automatically reloads the page, by example:

> https://our.jenkins.instances/blue/organizations/jenkins/build-names/detail/feature/pipelines/12041/tests/

But then I get this error:
[image]

I feel that blue ocean uses some kind of "browser-only-navigation" but there is a missing addon to their server, but I've no idea what or how to add it?

We are running jenkins on a windows server.

Answer (score 0):

I found that in my NGINX configuration, I was having a trailing `/` in the `proxy_pass`.

This is detailed here:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41425